# Cannot access keycloak - quarkus protected resource

Tags: java, openshift, keycloak, quarkus

Currently I have a keycloak server deployed on openshift and a quarkus rest service application with a secured resource that can be accessed using bearer token. I have read quarkus security related documentation but cannot access the secured resource. Allways get 401 status.

Those are the libraries I'm using in project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the application.properties file configuration:

**Update: added logs for quarkus and oidc libraries but cannot get any information about the issue in quarkus container log screen**

```
# CORS configuration
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.access-control-allow-credentials=true
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, origin, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with

# OpenId Connect configuration
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://keycloak-myproject.192.168.1.110.nip.io/auth/realms/secured-realm
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
quarkus.oidc.tenant-enabled=false

# Logging configuration
quarkus.log.level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcProvider".min-level=TRACE
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcProvider".level=TRACE

# resteasy security configuration
resteasy.role.based.security=true
```

And this is the resource code:

```
import io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken;
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.cache.NoCache;

@Path("/api")
public class SecuredResource {

  @Inject
  SecurityIdentity identity;

  @Inject
  JsonWebToken jwt;

  @GET
  @RolesAllowed("USERS")
  @NoCache
  @Path("/secured")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String secured() {
    String userName = identity.getPrincipal().getName();
    return userName;
  }

}
```

From quarkus container terminal I can access keycloak server using

```
curl -v -X GET $keycloak_url -H "Authorization: Bearer "$access_token
```

And a 200 status is returned; but cannot access to the secured resource.

So, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://keycloak-myproject.192.168.1.110.nip.io/auth/realms/secured-realm
```

Are you sure that url exists?

Did you try to access it? Was it successful?

Because, when I try to access similar url on my server:

```
https://users.skycomposer.net/auth/realms/secured-realm
```

it returns "Page Not Found".

Here is my keycloak configuration for Spring Boot application:

```
#Keycloak Configuration
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://users.skycomposer.net/auth
keycloak.realm=SpringBootKeycloak
keycloak.resource=login-app
keycloak.public-client=true
```

I think for **Quarkus** it should be similar, so you might try this configuration too.

See this article for more details on how to setup **Keycloak Server**:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak

P.S. If this configuration doesn't help, then, please, provide security configuration for your **Quarkus** application.

My **security configuration** for **Spring Boot Application** looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Submits the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider to the AuthenticationManager
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    // Specifies the session authentication strategy
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/customers*", "/users*")
            .hasRole("user")
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

But for **Quarkus** it should be different of course. In any case, your **Quarkus Security Configuration** might help to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: Hello @Mykhailo, thanks for reply. As for the question are you sure that url exists? yes, the url comes from a local okd cluster and keycloak server can be accessed from quarkus container. I have tested it from container's terminal. The issue is that I cannot access the secured rest service. I have tried adding logs for quarkus but don't get any information about what it is happening. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you configured your realm "**secured-realm**" correctly. For more details, see this article: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization.

According to this article, your quarkus keycloak configuration should look like this:

```
# OIDC Configuration
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=backend-service
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none

# Enable Policy Enforcement
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true
```

At least configure and specify **client-id**, it is definitely missing in your configuration. Regarding other parameters, I'm not sure, you need to experiment.

2. From quarkus container terminal you can access keycloak server using

> ```
> curl -v -X GET $keycloak_url -H "Authorization: Bearer "$access_token
> ```

But this is your "**keycloak admin**" user!

It has nothing to do with access to your secured resources!

Your secured resources should be protected with other users, by creating new users in "**admin console**".

3. Make sure that you created **new user** in "**admin console**".

For example, if you created new user "**user1**" with password "**test123**" in **admin console**, you should access your secured resources with "**user1**", not with "**keycloak admin**".

4. Make sure that your **new user** "**user1**" has role "**USERS**". Your current secured resource is protected with role "**USERS**":

> @RolesAllowed("USERS")

You can create new roles and assign them to users in the **keycloak admin console**. This is why you need "**keycloak admin**" user: to access keycloak console, create new users, specify passwords for new users and assign roles to these users. But don't try to access your secured resources with "**keycloak admin**" user!

Access your secured resources with different user, which you created in the "**keycloak admin**" console!

For more details, on how to create new users in **keycloak admin console** see this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak